# On Angular14 Migration: ror: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'EventEmitter')

Tags: angular14upgrade

I am upgrading from angular13 to angular14 meanwhile facing issue with EventEmitter like
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'EventEmitter')
Error Page:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emn4O.png)

Tryings from my side:
I thought its related some bundling issue so
I have run commands like Removed node_modules and run "npm cache clean --force"
and then "npm install"

but nothing is working

Please Help me on this issue.